# How do I disconnect Bluetooth headset while in call

Tags: bluetooth, hands-free

Does anyone know how to disconnect from a Bluetooth headset/handsfree device while in a call? Sometimes when I'm getting into my car while on a call, the handsfree in the car will take over the call before I'm ready to hand the call off. I've been turning off the Bluetooth to take the call back, but that is cumbersome,  my palm phone before had an option on the call screen whenever on a call with Bluetooth to simply disconnect the hands free device.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your phone (please update your question with your specific model), the call screen does have an option to turn off Bluetooth. That will turn off Bluetooth Audio Routing for just that current call (and conference calls made while that one is active/on hold).

I've only used CyanogenMod; CM6 & CM7 both have this option on the call screen. If your phone's UI has been customized by the vendor, it may have been removed.