# In-call speaker volume fixed too "low" while smartwatch connected via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, calls, volume-control

When my smartwatch (a cheap noname MTK 6260A device probably running Nucleus (most likely a clone of the ZGPax S29), and controlled by the BTNotification app on my Android device) is connected to my *LG P880* (running CyanogenMod Kitkat 4.4.4), and I receive or make a call, volume is quite low – I hardly can hear the other side. Volume rockers seem to have no effect (maybe connected to [Volume Rocker only controls Bluetooth In-call Volume; cannot control all other volumes](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106943/16575) which I just found – need to check that with the next call I make). I didn't have that issue before I got and connected the smartwatch.

My guess is it is …

- the reason of the linked question (volume rockers bound to bluetooth)
- that funny "max volume ear protection" we had mentioned here a couple of times

Apart from switching Bluetooth off whenever there's a call in progress (which I probably could do with [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker)):

> **Is there any way I could increase volume (or get the rocker off the Bluetooth part and back to the built-in "ear speaker" to control/raise the volume)?**

Note that audio is *not* routed to Bluetooth (I've explicitly disabled that, as otherwise everyone around would hear the other side via the speakers of my smartwatch), call volume is already set to 100% – and yes, I've checked with *Settings › Audio* already. Also, I've already checked with …

- [How to set in-call volume](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4113/16575)
- [How do I disconnect Bluetooth headset while in call](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9805/16575) (different issue)
- [Disable calls through Bluetooth smartwatch but show call status](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132497/16575) (remotely related, but no answer)
- [Why does the in-call volume change on its own on my Samsung Galaxy S3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/84154/16575) might be related (that BTNotifier stuff really is a bit buggy), but there's no update to BTNotifier available (in fact, I had to sideload the app from the manufacturer's site as the playstore version doesn't work with the watch)

Comment: Trying to get a decent volume out of anything is one of my biggest Android frustrations.

Comment: @MatthewRead thing is the volume *is* decent as long as the smartwatch isn't connected. I'd have gone straight to *Tasker* if there weren't the issue with the smartwatch not automatically reconnecting properly when BT returns (I have to disconnect and reconnect manually then to get notifications etc. working again). I might still revert to that if there's no other solution – as a phone makes absolutely no sense if one cannot make proper phone calls ;) Given I rarely get more than 2 calls a day, it might even bearable.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall the BT notification. By uninstalling it, the volume on the smartwatch will return to normal function, the best it will be.

The only other way is to install a volume booster from the Play Store.

Comment: Though it's no longer relevant to me as I don't have that watch anymore: how is this solving the issue? It's a comment at best, not an answer, sorry.